# Proving that $\int_{a}^{b}f>0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

If $f:[a,b]→R$ is continuous and non negative on $[a,b]$ and if $f(y)>0$ for some $y \in [a,b]$ how can I prove that $\int_{a}^{b}f>0$. Any answers will be much appreciated.

Comment: Let $f(y) = c > 0$. What can you say about the set $\{ x : f(x) \geqslant c/2\}$?

Comment: The set contains y since f(y)>c/2

Comment: And what does continuity additionally yield?

Comment: That we can find an interval where f(x)>c/2 ?

Comment: Right. And if the length of that interval is $l$, we know $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx \geqslant l \cdot c/2 > 0$.

Comment: That means I have to find δ. Any tip for that?

Comment: You don't need to find it, you only need to show that it exists. $\delta$ depends of $f$; for any given $f$ it is usually not difficult to find an explicit $y$ and $\delta$, but no $\delta > 0$ works for _all_ $f$ simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Hint. By using continuity of $f$ and $f(y) \gt 0$ find a $\delta$ such that in the interval $(y- \delta, y+\delta)$,   $f$ is positive. Now we are through?

Comment: I can take  ϵ=f(y)/2. Then f(x)>f(y)/2 in the interval (y−δ,y+δ). How can I find δ?

Comment: by the continuity of $f$ you will get a $\delta$ for $\epsilon = f(y)/2$. this is the $\delta$ in my answer. for more clear argument take $\epsilon = f(y)/4$.